# Include pyplot with slider to presentation

Tags: python, plotly, powerpoint, beamer

I looking to embed the html file of my figure to a presentation (ppt or beamer).
I am not able to find a way to do it. Do you have any idea?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o0-J-WMekReCU4cwNP2SqMrx9a-37pl/view?usp=sharing

The other possibility I find is to use HTML to create my presentation.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the code? Have you tried anything?
Could not understand what you want exactly!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Jupyter Notebook to make your presentation. There, you can add your interactive plotly-plots, edit code or do all sorts of cool stuff while presenting your slides. Take a look at this guide: https://medium.com/@mjspeck/presenting-code-using-jupyter-notebook-slides-a8a3c3b59d67